# (Marshmallow) Microphone stops working randomly in Viber, Skype etc

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, microphone

Every once in a while, the microphone on my S7 Edge (running Android 6.0.1) stops working, which I notice when someone calls on the phone/Viber/Skype, and the other side cannot hear me whereas I hear them. Rebooting always fixes it, but is still very annoying nonetheless. Has anyone noticed this and found a workaround? many thanks..

Comment: Affects me too on a Motorola Photon Q with the March 21 build of Cyanogenmod 13 (Android 6.0.1) from http://forum.xda-developers.com/photon-q-4g-lte/development/cyanogenmod-13-0-photon-q-android-6-x-t3304838 . I've tried adb logcat and not found any clues so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I accidentally stumbled upon the solution: The problem is caused by the Total Recorder app.